# Send private message with phpbb - Delphi

Tags: delphi

I've spent some hours trying to understand why this simply doesn't work, with no success ;(

I want to send private messages with my delphi application.

I can login, read and delete the messages, but I can't manage to send messages (my forum use phpbb3).

Analysing the post data, I got this:

```
Post URL: http://example.com/ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose&action=post&sid=xxxxx

Post Data:
username_list=
icon=0
subject=assunto
message=texto
address_list[u][2]=to
lastclick=xxxx
status_switch=0
post=Submit
attach_sig=on
creation_time=xxxx
form_token=xxx
```

The xxx values I need to get before send. I've manually checked the values, and they are correct.

My Code:

```
procedure Envia();
var
  form_token, cr_time, sid: string;
  pp: TStringList;
begin
  //download the page to get the values (token, sid...)
  FPageSource.Text := FCon.Get('http://example.com/ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose&u=2');

  //form token
  form_token := TRegEx.Match(FPageSource.Text, 'form_token" value="(\w+)"').Groups[1].Value;

  //creation time
  cr_time := TRegEx.Match(FPageSource.Text, 'creation_time" value="(\w+)"').Groups[1].Value;

  //sid
  sid := TRegEx.Match(FPageSource.Text, 'sid=(\w+)').Groups[1].Value;

  //data
  pp := TStringList.Create;
  pp.Add('username_list=');
  pp.Add('icon=0');
  pp.Add('subject=assunto');
  pp.Add('message=mensagem');
  pp.Add(HttpEncode('address_list[u][2]') + '=to');
  pp.Add('lastclick=' + cr_time);
  pp.Add('status_switch=0');
  pp.Add('post=Submit');
  pp.Add('attach_sid=on');
  pp.Add('creation_time=' + cr_time);
  pp.Add('form_token=' + form_token);

  //send
  FPageSource.Text := FCon.Post('http://example.com/ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose&action=post&sid=' + sid, pp);

  //The result in FPageSource is my inbox, my post data was
  //ignored by phpbb ;(

end;
```

NOTE:

- FCon = TIdHttp
- FPageSource = TStringList
- HttpEncode = function in HttpApp unit
- Using Delphi xe6

-- I've sent a message with Opera and captured the post data with Fiddler, [here the image](http://s30.postimg.org/mg3bbz5g1/fiddler_phpbb.png). As you can see, the data structure is the same, why isn't working ?

Comment: You captured the request from Opera; where is the equivalent capture from your program? Do they match? In other words, how do you know you're really sending what you think you're sending?

Comment: @RobKennedy the post data is the same, but the return code is 302, and if you look closely you'll see that the body size is 0. check the new image: [New Image](http://i.imgur.com/HngHvEj.png) -- Edit: HandleRedirects = true, same result >.<

Comment: What about the headers? Both sent and received. Are they the same, too?

Comment: @RobKennedy [Another Image](http://i.imgur.com/3N9EDWT.png) You think the **keep-alive** is causing this ?

Comment: I doubt it, although the Expect header in its place looks suspicious. I think you're getting closer. From the IP address, I assume you have access to the server. Maybe you could check its logs to see what the server thinks is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem will be simple - wait time (spam protection). Plus you should probably add the user first - one more request.

This code should work fine

```
  s:=FCon.Get('http://.../ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose');

  pp.Add('username_list=UserToADd');
  pp.Add('add_to=Add');
  pp.Add('icon=0');
  pp.Add('subject=');
  pp.Add('addbbcode20=100');
  pp.Add('message=');
  pp.Add('lastclick='+...);
  pp.Add('status_switch=0');
  pp.Add('creation_time='+...);
  pp.Add('form_token='+...);

  s:=FCon.Post('http://.../ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose&action=post&sid=...', pp);

  Sleep(2000); // <-- wait here

  pp.Clear;
  pp.Add('username_list=');
  pp.Add('icon=0');
  pp.Add('subject=XX');
  pp.Add('addbbcode20=100');
  pp.Add('message=YY');
  pp.Add('address_list[u][2]=to');
  pp.Add('lastclick='+...);
  pp.Add('status_switch=0');
  pp.Add('post=Submit');
  pp.Add('attach_sid=on');
  pp.Add('creation_time='+...);
  pp.Add('form_token='+...);  // new one

  s:=FCon.Post('http://.../ucp.php?i=pm&mode=compose&action=post&sid=...', pp);
```

Comment: OMG, worked like a charm! But I've moved the Sleep to above the FCon.Post. Thank you.